# Disable input for a single character in a textbox

Tags: vb.net

I have an application that works with a 3rd party ticketing software to submit/update tickets. The issue I am having is, the ticketing software reads the character : as a new input. What I am trying to do is disable ONLY : from being entered into a textbox.

I have done some research and found ways to, Disable letters/numbers/special, but not one for only a single one.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by single one? Could you give a sample?

Comment: @AT-2016 Sure. I want to disable the ability for users to type a colon in a textbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 Private Sub txtchange() Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace(":", "")
    TextBox1.SelectionStart = TextBox1.Text.Length
End Sub
```

Replace `TextBox1` with your textbox name

Comment: Perfect, super simple way to handle this, not sure why I did not think of it!

Answer (score 1):

If you are linked to JQuery, you can check if it is a colon and return false if a colon was entered like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.phoneInput').keypress(function(key) {
       if(key.charCode ==58) return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

To find the Unicode value of a character, I tend to use this page on W3Schools:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_event_key_charcode

I hope this helps!

Comment: Not using JQuery, but I am saving this for the future, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can disable or prevent users for special characters with JavaScript. As an example:

```
<head>
    $('input[type="text"]').keydown(function(e){
    var ingnore_key_codes = [8,32];

    if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, ingnore_key_codes) >= 0)
      {
          e.preventDefault();
      }
   });
</head

<form action="#">
     <input type="text" />
</form>
```

For more, check this - http://blog.troygrosfield.com/2010/12/01/preventing-character-input-using-javascript/

Comment: Not the answer/fix I went with, but this is great information, thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to ascii, 58 is the ascii integer for 58

```
  Private Sub txtchange() Handles TextBox1.Keypress
    if asc(e.keychar) = 58 Then
      e.handled = true
      Messagebox.show("Colon is not allowed")
    end if
   End Sub
```

Comment: this code will prevent the user from the first place inputting a colon